# Remove query string and append value to URL-path

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a URL in the following way.

If the user visits:

```
https://example.com/clientes/?dni=12345
```

Get redirected to:

```
https://example.com/clientes/12345
```

That is, I need to remove this part `?dni=` from the URL and redirect to:

```
https://example.com/clientes/12345
```

So far I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dni=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^clientes$ /%1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It still doesn't work for me, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> :
> RewriteRule ^clientes$ /%1? [R=301,L]
> ```

Your example URL includes a trailing slash, but your `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not. This would also redirect to `/12345`, not `/clinetes/12345` as stated.

Try the following instead, at the top of the root `.htaccess` file (before any existing WordPress directives):

```
:
RewriteRule ^clientes/$ /$0%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `clientes/`.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4) discards the original query string. (This is preferred to appending an empty query string on the *substitution*.)

Comment: Thx. It´s working.

My final solutión:

`code`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dni=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^clientes/$ /$0%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @AngelDiaz You're welcome. Btw, the `RewriteBase` directive is not required there (unless you have other rules it should apply to).